# Double clicking to jump to end of text

Tags: godot

I'm trying to make a dating sim and one of the things I'm trying to do is have a mouse click in the middle of the game writting the string instantly write it all.

```
    extends RichTextLabel

var dialog = ["Hello There", "how are you"]
var page = 0


func _ready():

    set_bbcode(dialog[page])
    set_visible_characters(0)

func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if get_visible_characters() > get_total_character_count():
            if page < dialog.size()-1:
                page += 1
                set_bbcode(dialog[page])
                set_visible_characters(0)

func _on_Timer_timeout():
    set_visible_characters(get_visible_characters() + 1)
```

To accomplish this I want to measure the visible characters in the bbcode; but i just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i figured out how to do it here.

```
func _input(event):
if event is InputEventMouseButton:
    if get_visible_characters() > get_total_character_count():
        if page < dialog.size()-1:
            page += 1
            set_bbcode(dialog[page])
            set_visible_characters(0)
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if get_visible_characters() < get_total_character_count():
            set_visible_characters(get_total_character_count())
```

Just put another event type input inside the already existing input event, then check to see if get_visible_characters is less then get_total_character_count. If true set the visible character to the total character count.